# Use of 'Could' in the Past Tense

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

What are the possible meanings and implications of the following sentences:

1. He could come yesterday.
2. He could not come yesterday.
3. He could have come yesterday.
4. He could not have come yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

All of them make sense except, I would suggest, the first one.

1. If he was invited and came one would say 'He came yesterday'. If however he was invited, indicated he could come, but nonetheless declined, one would say 'He could have come yesterday'.
2. 'He could not come yesterday' would indicate that he had been invited, but had been unable to come.
3. & 4. These would be the perfectly usual ways of indicating whether or not someone would have been able to come, had they been invited.

Comment: How does the possibility of going change the tense? I don't think this answer is correct, but would like to hear other points of view [no downvote, just hmmm].

Comment: @CarlSmith They are only intended as examples of circumstances in which you would use those expressions. They are not meant to be exhaustive. One could write endlessly on the matter.

Comment: I don't think any of the OP's four examples are correct English. You seem to be saying the use of *come* over *came* in a past tense is OK if the person was able to go. I don't understand that at all.

Comment: 'He could have came' seems incorrect to my Toronto-based, doctorate in the Humanities ears.

Comment: @CarlSmith But 'come' is the past participle. *He has come*, *he could have come* etc. You couldn't say 'he could have came', could you?

Comment: Good point @WS2. `+1` Sorry; you're right. I wasn't sure, and should have left it.

Answer (score 0):

I like this question because "can" and "could" are common but part of an irregular verb. There is no infinitive "to can" one would use "to be able" 
So to answer the questions:

1) If the sense of "could" was intended to be the past tense of can then it is more idiomatic to say, "He was able to come yesterday". This is because of the dual usage of the word "could": one as "has the possibility to" and one as "was able to" 
If the sentence was intended to be conditional then it does not really make sense since it involves both past and present tenses.

Could in the conditional sense can be replaced with "have/has the possibility to" 
I have the possibility to come yesterday is a mix of tenses and thus illogical as long as time travel is not invented.
It would have to read "he could come tomorrow" to make sense since it has not happened yet and the sense of could is conditional (he could come tomorrow [if....]).

2) This is in the sense of he was not able to come yesterday for some reason.

3) this is in the sense that he presence was conditional upon an event but in the end, he did not attend.

4) this has the sense that due to circumstances it was not possible, even conceivable, that he attended and that he had no choice in the matter. It explains, to some degree, his absence rather than just simply say "he did not attend" which implies that he had a choice.